# Java list files wrong name for folders with accents

Tags: java

I have an application running on tomcat. I need to list all folders under a certain path on my server. But if some folders have accents on their name, the accents are replaced with special characters. For example for a folder named "accentué" the returned name is "accentu��".

The problem appears on a centOS 6 server but not locally on my Ubuntu 20.04 laptop.

Here is my code:

```
    Path folderPath = Paths.get(path);
    try (DirectoryStream<Path> directoryStream = Files.newDirectoryStream(folderPath)) {
        for (Path childPath : directoryStream) {
            if (!Files.isRegularFile(childPath)) {
                log.info("Folder name: " + childPath.getFileName());
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //
    }
```

I am using JDK11. I already set variables for tomcat as following

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8"
```

My OS value for LANG is en_US.UTF-8 (oddly if I try to get LANG from my java code the LANG variable is null).
Also, the same code in the same machine but with jshell works well.

Comment: getFilename() like everything in Java returns a Unicode string, as a sequence of UTF-16 characters.  The 'log' call presumably converts to something else, probably UTF-8.  When you look at the log, whatever program you use needs to understand UTF-8 and needs to use a font that has those characters.  You need to figure out at which stage this all fails.  I'd start 'in the middle' by looking at the log with a hex editor.

Comment: @user14644949 I tried to open the logs with xxd, but the hexedecimal does not correspond to my accentuated characters (I used hexadecimal to text converter to check). Also I just let the log line in my piece of code, but in my original code I pass the name to my front as a string (with "childPath.getFileName().toString()" and the result is the same.

Comment: The log file is likely in UTF-8, not the UTF-16 of a Java String value.  You have to understand how to interpret UTF-8 as hex.  You need to do this manually -- using some "hex to text coverter" just adds one more stage of uncertainty into the whole thing, since "hex to text" depends on using the right character code for the conversion.

Comment: 'é' in UTF-16 is 00e9; as UTF-8 it is c3 a9.  What do you see in the hex editor?

Comment: I see "efbf" for my "é"

Comment: Then my guess is that the 'log' call translated the UTF-16 from the Java string into some unknown character code (not UTF-8).